# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

I am reading through a csv file and writing results to a logfile, "p.log".  Although I am converting the data into a string before writing it to the file, and doing so successfully through several iterations, I keep running into a situation where I eventually get this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'.

I will provide a snippet of my code as well as the result printed to my screen:

```
p=open("p.log","w")

for line in f:#parse lines following the headerline
    line = line.split(",")
    print line, type(str(line))
    p.write('string: '+str(line)+'\n')

['14-04-21 08:30:00.973000', 'EEM06211440.5P', 'EEM', '2014-06-21', '40.50', 'P', '16084', 'AUTO', 'PHLX', '0.82', '10', '0.82', '31', '0.88', '31', '0.06', '0.00', '0.06', 'Y', 'AN', '2', 'AN', '2', 'Bid', '31', '0.0000', '2', 'AN\r\n'] <type 'str'>
['14-04-21 08:30:00.974000', 'MU06211425C', 'MU', '2014-06-21', '25.00', 'C', '0', 'AUTO', 'PSE', '1.57', '11', '1.56', '11', '1.67', '30', '0.11', '0.01', '0.10', 'Y', 'Z', '1', 'IXH', '3', 'Mid', '0', '0', '0', '\r\n'] <type 'str'>
['14-04-21 08:30:00.975000', 'QQQ04251481C', 'QQQ', '2014-04-25', '81.00', 'C', '1585', 'AUTO', 'AMEX', '5.70', '1', '5.20', '82', '5.70', '67', '0.50', '0.50', '0.00', 'Y', 'AINX', '4', 'AINX', '4', 'Ask', '67', '-22.3881', '4', 'AINX\r\n'] <type 'str'>
['14-04-21 08:30:00.976000', 'MPEL05171435.66C', 'MPEL', '2014-05-17', '35.66', 'C', '409', 'AUTO', 'ISE', '2.20', '20', '2.20', '384', '3.10', '20', '0.90', '0.00', '0.90', 'N', 'AI', '2', 'I', '1', 'Bid', '384', '94.7917', '2', 'AI\r\n'] <type 'str'>
['14-04-21 08:30:00.978000', 'AAPL7071914500C', 'AAPL', '2014-07-19', '500.00', 'C', '670', 'AUTO', 'AMEX', '34.85', '3', '34.15', '1', '35.05', '12', '0.90', '0.70', '0.20', 'Y', 'A', '1', 'A', '1', 'Mid', '0', '0', '0', '\r\n'] <type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q1.py", line 83, in <module>
    p.write('string: '+str(line)+'\n')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'
```

As you can see there are several lines printed without fail, until the line with 'AAPL' in it.  Not sure why there's an error on this line and not others.

Comment: Show us the code where you declare the file handle `p`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere in the code you didn't post is a line that overwrites your variable `p` with an integer.

Comment: thanks, I found I forgot there was another variable named p buried in my code

Comment: In my case, having the method .truncate on the same line as 'open' statement for the new text file to write to was the culprit. I had to put .truncate on a new line.