# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write a simulator in python for spiking neural networks.
Network has been planned to be built from neurons and connections, as below:

Connection class:

```
class Connection(object):

connectionType = 0   
weight = [[0 for x in range(1)] for x in range(9)]

def __init__():
   self.threshold = 0
   self.connectionType = 0
```

And Neuron class:

```
import Connection

class Neuron(object):

ID = 1
OveralPotential = 0

def __init__(self):
    global ID
    self.input = [[0 for x in range(1)] for x in range(9)]
    self.output = [[0 for x in range(1)] for x in range(9)]
    self.id = Neuron.ID
    Neuron.ID += 1

def connect(srcNeuron, dstNeuron, connectionType):
    srcNeuron.output[dstNeuron.id] = 1
    dstNeuron.input[srcNeuron.id] = 1
    Connection.Connection.connectionType = connectionType

if __name__ == "__main__":

n1 = Neuron()
n2 = Neuron()
n3 = Neuron()
print("ID of the 3rd neuron is {0}".format(n3.id))
n4 = Neuron()
n5 = Neuron()

Neuron.connect(1,3,1)
Neuron.connect(1,4,1)
Neuron.connect(1,5,1)
Neuron.connect(2,3,1)
Neuron.connect(2,4,1)
Neuron.connect(2,5,1)
```

But here is the stacktrace:

```
ID of the 3rd neuron is 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio      12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Mic
rosoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line   106, in
exec_file
exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio   12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Mic
rosoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82,  in
exec_code
exec(code_obj, global_variables)
File "C:\Users\Matinking\Documents\Visual Studio  2013\Projects\NeuroSimulation
\NeuroSimulation\Neuron.py", line 31, in <module>
Neuron.connect(1,3,1)
File "C:\Users\Matinking\Documents\Visual Studio  2013\Projects\NeuroSimulation
\NeuroSimulation\Neuron.py", line 16, in connect
srcNeuron.output[dstNeuron.id] = 1
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'output'
```

I checked the possible duplicates in this case, like:

[AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769921/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-split)

and

[AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204593/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-write)

But none of them gave me enough insight to handle above stuff.
How should I resolve it?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling the method `Neuron.connect()` with integer arguments then tying to access the attribute `.connect` in the first line of that method. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing integer values to the method

```
def connect(srcNeuron, dstNeuron, connectionType):
    srcNeuron.output[dstNeuron.id] = 1
    dstNeuron.input[srcNeuron.id] = 1
    Connection.Connection.connectionType = connectionType
```

when you are invoking it

```
Neuron.connect(1,3,1)
Neuron.connect(1,4,1)
Neuron.connect(1,5,1)
Neuron.connect(2,3,1)
Neuron.connect(2,4,1)
Neuron.connect(2,5,1)
```

I think you actually meant to specify the neurons instead of integers

```
Neuron.connect(n1,n3,n1)
Neuron.connect(n1,n4,n1)
Neuron.connect(n1,n5,n1)
Neuron.connect(n2,n3,n1)
Neuron.connect(n2,n4,n1)
Neuron.connect(n2,n5,n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `connect` function expects two objects of type `Neuron`, not a neuron id. You are passing an id, that is an `int` and python tries to access the output field.